# Connect to AMPQ RabbitMQ on port 5671

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to connect to a RabbitMQ remote machine to read queue messages and currently I am using port 5672 which is sending the auth message over plain text so I need to get it working on port 5671 but it's failing.

Does it require anymore configuration then just changing the port number below?

I am using the nodeJS plugin for ampq-callback to connect

`amqp.connect('amqp://xxx:5671', function(err,conn) {`

Answer (score 0):

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html

https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html

Yes, you must set up TLS in RabbitMQ.